# Statistics at user level in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, usage-statistics, visitor-statistic

We have a very simple statistics collection global filter on our web application, but now we would like to collection more information and I thought that may be somebody already has done this, so are there any good user tracking modules for asp.net mvc with ability to load custom data, view statistical charts/etc, simple search in SO/Google/Nuget gallery haven't brought me anything useful.

Comment: I can recommend external general performance monitoring tool http://newrelic.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Google Analytics supports tracking at user level:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables